# Set field in else case clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I would like to set a field in my case clause in my view:

```
CREATE VIEW view AS
    SELECT
        CO AS C, 
        ErrorO AS Error,
    case
        WHEN BO IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
        ELSE ErrorO = "true"
    END AS B
FROM table;
```

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

How can I set `Error` to a value?

**Edit 1**

Some values in the Table:

```
+------+------+------+-------+
|  AO  |  BO  |  Co  | ErrorO|
+------+------+------+-------+
| Data | Data | Data | false |
| Data |      | Data | false |
| Data |      | Data | true  |
+------+------+------+-------+
```

What should output the view:

```
+------+-------+------+
|  C   | Error |  B   |
+------+-------+------+
| Data | false |  1   |
| Data | true  |      |
| Data | true  |      |
+------+-------+------+
```

Comment: So you want to select `C`, `ErrorO`, and s string that is '1' in case `AO` is not null and `true` otherwise? Or what else? It would help, if you showed some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I have a table with Raw data. I'm using the view to transform some fields depending of other fields. If `Error0` is `true` then keep `true`. If you find that `AO` is `NULL` then the data is corrupt so I want to set `Error` to `True`. I don't want to update `ErrorO` directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @Error  = 
CASE WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
    ELSE 'true' END
```

Comment: I can't manage to make it work. I will update my post to give better context.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title,
       CASE 
          WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN '1'

          ELSE 'Unknown Value'
       END
FROM   tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES (1,'NOTNULL'),
               (2,NULL)
        ) AS ValuesTable(CO,AO)
)
SELECT CTE.CO AS C,
       CTE.AO AS A,
       CA.ErrorO AS Error
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CTE.AO IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
                         ELSE 'TRUE'
                    END AS ErrorO
            ) AS CA
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show `'true'` for `Error` instead of `ErrorO` when `BO` is null. You want to show `1` instead of `BO` when `BO` is not null.

```
select
  CO as C,
  case when BO is null then 'true' else ErrorO end as Error,
  case when BO is null then null else 1 end as B
from mytable;
```

Alternative for the case it's always about `BO` being null or not:

```
select CO as C, 'true' as Error, null as B from mytable where BO is null
union all
select CO as C, ErrorO as Error, 1 as B from mytable where BO is not null;
```

Comment: It's a little bit clearer now. 1) You want to show `CO`. 2) You want to show 1 for each `BO` that is not null and null for each `BO` that is null. 3) But as to `Error`: please define exactly when to show 'true', when to show 'false' and whether other values are possible. So far it sounded like `ErrorO` can contain any string. Is that the case or does it always contain 'true' or 'false'? Is null possible? And are you confusing `AO` and `BO` in your sample/result in regards to the error?

Comment: `Error0` is indeed a String in my case (not very smart). But basically it can be `true` or `false`. And I want, even if `Error0` is already set to `true`, to display `Error` as `true` if `B IS NULL` .

Comment: if `BO` is null then replace `Error` with `true`.

Comment: Ok thank you, that what i thought. I have to make a special case clause for `ErrorO`.I have a lot of `case` clause with lot of `when` inside, I thought I could use the `ELSE` to change `Error`

Comment: No, it's one CASE expression per column in your results. If it's always about `BO` being null or not though, you can use two queries and glue the results with `UNION ALL`. I've updated my answer accordingly.